# Excel VBA detect if user selects either a parent or child node on a treeview

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform containing a treeview and 2 frames each with several textboxes, labels etc.

If  the user selects certain parents or any of their children, I want to hide 1 of the userform frames.
Using the code below, I am able to hide the frame if the user selects a child but if the user selects a parent I get a Run Time error 91 “Object variable or with block variable not set”

Changing Node.Parent to Node.Key hides the frame when the parent is selected but not when a child is selected.
How can I hide the frame if either is selected?
Any guidance would be welcome.

```
If Node.Parent = "North" Or Node.Parent = "South" Or Node.Parent = "East” _
or Node.Parent = "West" Then
UserForm1.Frame1.Visible = False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If Userform1.TreeView1.Nodes(<name of node>).Parent Is Nothing Then
    <this is a parent node>
Else
    <this is a child node>
End If
```

You can get the name of the selected node using hittest during a "mousedown" event. Button, shift, x, and y are automatically populated by the event

```
Private Sub TreeView1_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As stdole.OLE_XPOS_PIXELS, ByVal y As stdole.OLE_YPOS_PIXELS)

        'hittest is looking at twips, x,y=pixels. 15 twips to a pixel (*15) to make it 
         <name of node> = TreeView1.HitTest(x * 15, y * 15)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your response; I have been out of action for a while.